Encrypt api data using Angular, C#, CryptoJS
I need to encrypt the API request and response, to hide the sensitive data in payload and preview of network tab. I'm using CryptoJS concept, angular as front end, C# as backend.
In my project there many many api's so, I should not change anything in all api, I should write code in common place like http-interceptor and middle ware.
I have encrypted request data in http-interceptor and decrypted the data in service side, done business logic, now again encrypted the data to send as repsonse.
when I see in network tab, payload and preview got encrypted, but error is throwing in UI side,
method 1:
when I use responseType: 'text' as 'json' in UI side, response is coming as string and output is coming, but in login.comp.ts we used as json format,I can't do JSON.Parse in each api, when I tried to JSON.Parse in http-interceptor.ts it is throwing error like this
Error: Response is not a string.
at http.mjs:1268:39
method 2:
when I didn't use responseType: 'text' as 'json', response is not even coming to http-interceptor , throwing error as
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'A', "Alk/tp1njw"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
I need to encrypt the API request and response, to hide the sensitive data in payload and preview of network tab. I'm using CryptoJS concept, angular as front end, C# as backend
In Angular
login.comp.ts:

this.loginservice.ValidateLogin()
.subscribe((res: UserModel) => {
    this.LoginValue = res;
})

login.service.ts:

ValidateLogin(){
  var ins_Object = {
    'key': 'output'
  }
  return this.customHttpService.postwithouttoken(this.baseUrl + '/api/Security/ValidateLoginUser/', ins_Object).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError));
}

custom-http.service.ts

postwithouttoken(url: string, body: any) {
      const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "x-lims":UserService.AuthToken != null ? UserService.AuthToken : "Undefined",
              "x-session-userid":
              UserService.UserId + "^" + UserService.DisplayName
          }),
          responseType: 'text' as 'json'
      };
      return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), httpOptions).pipe(
              finalize(() => {
              this.onEnd();
          })
      );
}

http-interceptor.ts:

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        base64Key: LoginService.OtherID1 ? LoginService.OtherID1 : "", base64IV:LoginService.OtherID2 ? LoginService.OtherID2 : "" 
       }
  });

  const newReq = req;
 
  var clonedReq= newReq.clone();  
      clonedReq = clonedReq.clone({ body: this.EncryptPassword(newReq.body) });
    
  return next.handle(clonedReq)
  .pipe(     
    map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {          
        if (event.body) {
          if(typeof event.body === 'string'){
            const decryptedBody = this.DecryptPassword(event.body);
            const parsedBody = JSON.parse(decryptedBody);
            event = event.clone({ body: parsedBody });
            return event;
          }else{
            return event;
          }
        }   
      }
    }),    
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return throwError(() => { new Error(displayError)});
    })
 );
  

 EncryptPassword(password: string) {
  var OD1  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(LoginService.OtherID1);
  var OD2  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(LoginService.OtherID2);

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password), OD1,
    {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: OD2,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
  var rstring: string = encrypted.toString();
  var plusCount = rstring.split('+').length - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < plusCount; i++) {
    rstring = rstring.replace('+', '[^]');
  }
  var slashCount = rstring.split('/').length - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < slashCount; i++) {
    rstring = rstring.replace('/', '^');
  }
  return rstring;
}

DecryptPassword(password: String) {
  password = password.replaceAll('[^]','+').replaceAll('^','/');
  var OD1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(LoginService.OtherID1);
  var OD2 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(LoginService.OtherID2);
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(password, OD1,
    { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: OD2, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

}


In C#:
SecutiryController.cs:
namespace LIMS.WebService.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Security")]
    [LIMSAuthorize]

      public class SecurityController : ApiController
    {
         [HttpPost]
        [Route("ValidateLoginUser")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ValidateLoginUser(LIMSInstance ObjLIMSInstance)
        {
             
           svcresult = new UserLogon();
            svcresult.DateFormatWithTime = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateFormatForUI"];
            svcresult.LogonSuccessful = false;
            svcresult.Message = "MISMATCHAPPVERSION";
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, svcresult);
        }
    }
}


LIMSAuthorize.cs:
namespace LIMS.WebService.Filters
{
    public sealed class LIMSAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
                var base64Key = "base64Key";
                var base64IV = "base64IV";
                string base64KeyStr = string.Empty;
                string base64IVStr = string.Empty;
  
                        IEnumerable<string> base64KeyValues = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("base64Key");
                        base64KeyStr = base64KeyValues.FirstOrDefault();
                   
                        IEnumerable<string> base64IVValues = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("base64IV");
                        base64IVStr = base64IVValues.FirstOrDefault();

                    var encryptedPayload = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var decryptedPayload = Decrypt(encryptedPayload, base64KeyStr, base64IVStr);
                    actionContext.Request.Content = new StringContent(decryptedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");    
            
            return true;
        }

           private string Decrypt(string password, string base64Key, string base64IV)
        {
            var replacePlus = Convert.ToString(password.Replace("[^]", "+"));
            var replaceSlash = Convert.ToString(replacePlus.Replace('^', '/'));
            var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Key);
            var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64IV);

            var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(replaceSlash);
            var decriptedFromJavascript = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, keybytes, iv);
            return decriptedFromJavascript;
        }

        private static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] encryptedValue, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {

            string plaintext = null;
            using (Aes aesAlgorithm = Aes.Create())
            {

                var decryptor = aesAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

                using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encryptedValue))
                {
                    using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
    }
}

CustomException.cs:
namespace LIMS.WebService.Filters
{
  public class EncryptResponseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {   
 public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null && actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null)
            {
                var responseContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var base64Key = "base64Key";
                var base64IV = "base64IV";
                string base64KeyStr = string.Empty;
                string base64IVStr = string.Empty;

                    IEnumerable<string> base64KeyValues = actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("base64Key");
                    base64KeyStr = base64KeyValues.FirstOrDefault();

                    IEnumerable<string> base64IVValues = actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("base64IV");
                    base64IVStr = base64IVValues.FirstOrDefault();
                var encryptedContent = EncryptString(responseContent, base64KeyStr, base64IVStr);

                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(encryptedContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }

         public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string base64Key, string base64IV)
        {
            string sEncText = null;
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Key);
                aesAlg.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64IV);

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                    }

                    sEncText = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return sEncText;
        }
    }
}

